# Errai security with PicketLink

Tags: java, gwt, errai

I have this CustomAuthenticator for user with Errai Security:

```
public CustomAuthenticator extends BaseAuthenticator {
    @Override
    public void authenticate() {
        String userId = loginCredentials.getUserId();
        String password = loginCredentials.getPassword();
        User user = userDAO.fetchUserByName(userId);
        if (!BCrypt.checkpw(password, user.getPasswordHash())) {
            setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.FAILURE);
        } else {
            // Add to IDM
            IdentityQuery<UserImpl> query
                    = partitionManager.createIdentityManager().createIdentityQuery(UserImpl.class);
            query.setParameter(UserImpl.LOGIN_NAME, user.getUsername());
            List<UserImpl> result = query.getResultList();
            org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Role trial = new org.picketlink.idm.model.basic.Role("TRIAL");
            if (result.isEmpty()){
                UserImpl account = new UserImpl(user);
                partitionManager.createIdentityManager().add(account);
                partitionManager.createIdentityManager().updateCredential(account, new Password(password));
                partitionManager.createIdentityManager().add(trial);
                BasicModel.grantRole(partitionManager.createRelationshipManager(), account, trial);
                IdentityQuery<UserImpl> q
                        = partitionManager.createIdentityManager().createIdentityQuery(UserImpl.class);
                q.setParameter(UserImpl.LOGIN_NAME, user.getUsername());
                UserImpl u = q.getResultList().iterator().next();
                setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS);
                setAccount(u);
            } else {
                setStatus(AuthenticationStatus.SUCCESS);
                setAccount(result.iterator().next());

            }
            userEvent.fire(user);
        }
}
```

Even I check the seAccount Account to be set is ok, I am not sure if the Roles is persisted at list at the Picketlink side; because the response of the call:

```
Caller<AuthenticationService> authServiceCaller;
```

The Errai Security User returned although not null, the names is "ANONYMOUS" and role is "NOBODY" I'm not sure what's happening here.

**Update:**

The `login(username, password)` method returns the correct User and Role, but `getUser()` does not. This is the issue.